# How to overcome NullInjector error in karma while testing with ng test in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

In my Angular application I have successfully created a webpage. And it executed perfectly.

But when I tested using **ng test** it is showing some errors in karma. like

```
Spec List | Failures
AdminComponent > should create
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[DashboardService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'DashboardService', 'HttpClient', 'HttpClient' ] })
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[DashboardService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:1013:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11122:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11122:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:899:1)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:903:1)
    at Object.DashboardService_Factory [as factory] (ng:///DashboardService/ɵfac.js:5:44)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11289:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11111:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:24243:1)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:22142:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DashboardService } from '../dashboard.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ds:DashboardService,private http:HttpClient) { }
 public superuser:any;
  public userlist:any;
  public last_login:any;
  public logi_ip:any;
  public usersloginstatus:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ds.userslastlogin()
      .subscribe((usersloginstatus) => {
        this.usersloginstatus = usersloginstatus;

        console.log('obj4', usersloginstatus);
        this.superuser = this.usersloginstatus.superuser;
        this.userlist = this.usersloginstatus.users;
        console.log('obj5', this.superuser);
        console.log('obj6', this.userlist);
      },
      err => {
          console.log("Error", err)
        }
      );
}
  createActivity(){

    var userurlconf = '';
    let userprof = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    if (userprof.usertype == 'Admin') {
      userurlconf = '/api/activity/adminhistory';
    } else if (userprof.usertype == 'Super User') {
      userurlconf = '/api/activity/superuserhistory';
    } else {
      userurlconf = '/api/activity/userhistory';
    }
  
  
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };
    this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + userurlconf, JSON.stringify({ location: localStorage.getItem('cityname'),

    action_status: 1}), httpOptions).subscribe(
      (dataforlogin) => {
        console.log(dataforlogin);
  
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error", err)
      }
  
    );
  
  }
  }
```

**dashboard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

//import { AuthserviceService} from './authservice.service';
declare let L: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {
  public datas: any[];
  public mac: any;
  public ssid: any;
  // public signals:any;
  // public jammers:any[];
  public sensors: any[];
  public lt: number;
  public ln: number;
  //public jamst:any;
  public id: string;
  jammer: any;
  public drones: any;
  public Drone: any;
  Droneid: string;
  latlong: any = [];
  public dataforlogin: any[];
  public profile: any;
  public userslogin: any;
  public usertype: string;
  public usersloginstatus: any
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  create(post, token) {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
      })
    };
    this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/wifi/signals', httpOptions).subscribe(
      (datas: any[]) => {

        // localStorage.setItem("datas",JSON.stringify(datas));
        //this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error", err)
      }
    );
  }

  //api  for drones
  dronedetails(): Observable<object> {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };

    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/data/json', httpOptions)
    
  }
  
  setValues() {

  }
  
  sensordetails(): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/sensors', httpOptions)

}
jammerdetails(): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/jammers', httpOptions)
    //for lastlogin users

  }


  userslastlogin(): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl +'/api/activity/loginusers', httpOptions)

  }
  }
```

**dashboard.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';

describe('DashboardService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: DashboardService = TestBed.get(DashboardService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have tried multiple ways to overcome this, but I am not able to solve it.

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import HttpClientTestingModule, and mock your service.

```
import {} from ''; // Your imports

describe('DashboardService', () => {
  let service: DashboardService;

  const dashboardServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('DashboardService', {
    userslastlogin => of({})
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: DashboardService, useValue: dashboardServiceMock }
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(DashboardService);
  });

  // ...

});
```

Comment: But showing the errors If I change dashboard.service.spec.ts as above.Can you please rearrange the above code If I made any mistakes

Comment: It is not taking the of({}) .

Comment: Try to remove parenthesis of `userslastlogin` and add at the top `import { of } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: the above const dashboardServiceMock has to add after import statements and before desribe(..) right?

Comment: Thanks, but showing error as No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'userslastlogin'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `HttpClientModule` to `imports` in `module.ts` resolved my problem

```
    imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```